# How to connect to online database with local database in Drupal 8 site

Tags: 8, database

**EDITED**

How to connect then fetch data from online database to drupal 8 on localhost. Both of them using postgre as main database. I have followed this [tutorial](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167569/how-can-i-setup-multiple-database-connections-in-drupal-8) and change `settings.php`'s external host with ip from my online database. I try to fetch data with my module, refer to [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2710557#comment-11641647) but still not work, my module look like this:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\example\Controller;

class ExampleController {

  public function example() { 
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection('external');

    // Get a connection going
    $db = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection();

print_r($db->databaseType);
$query = $db->select('users', 'u')
    ->fields('u', ['name', 'email']);
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

print_r($result);

\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();
  }
}
```

I was edited this code, looks more simple, and now showing result

> pgsql
>   The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

this result only showing result from `print_r($db->databaseType);` but i still confuse, is this come from external database? Thank's for some help of this case.

Comment: Have you tried connecting with another client? Usually databases are configured to only allow local connections. If so, you won't be able to connect externally.

Comment: What does "still not work" mean exactly?

Comment: @Clive I have update my code and showing the result. Before this only showing blank page with unstoppable reload proses, that's I mind "still not work".

Comment: Can you provide the error message from the PHP error log?

Comment: @mradcliffe thank's for suggest to add PHP error log, I really sorry about this, finally found and fix this error. Variable connection that I use is not same with variable connection that I declare. Now i can access my online database in my localhost. 

I hope this can be useful when we need data from another db although it has different host.