# How to create a table in second database with hook_schema

Tags: 8, database, services, configuration

I want to use two databases, that works following: [How can I setup multiple database connections in Drupal 8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167569/how-can-i-setup-multiple-database-connections-in-drupal-8) .

I can set the connection in the settings.php file, access it by injecting a different database connection.

But how can I use a my .install file with hook_schema to create the tables in the second database?

Comment: Curious to know, why?

Comment: why two databases? to not spam the main db with click stream and other anaylitcs related data.