# Multiple databases

Tags: 8, database

I'm having trouble getting Drupal to switch between multiple databases. I have a system that involves connecting to an external database to retrieve data. I am using the following code inside of a form at build time to get some information for displaying in the form.

```
$connExternal = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('default', 'atavism');
$results = $connExternal->select('world');
$results->fields('world_name');
$data = $results->query();

$result = $data->fetchAll();

dpm(result);
```

However, when I visit the form, Drupal redirects me back to the install page, where it tells me that drupal is already installed. I have tried using `setActiveConnection()` as well, but the same thing keeps happening. I am not sure how to resolve it, and access the secondary database for retrieving the information I need.

Inside of my settings.php, I have this:

```
$databases['atavism']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'world',
  'username' => 'redacted',
  'password' => 'redacted',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You have to set it back after using. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167569/how-can-i-setup-multiple-database-connections

Comment: According to that article, using getConnection allows you to get the database without changing the global state. With that being said, I also call getConnection() at the bottom to the same effect.

Comment: Still trying to resolve this. No matter what I do, Drupal continues to redirect me to the install complete page.